# How primary key is related to stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

I am not getting the exact relation between primary key and stored procedure. And use of primary key in stored procedure. Please reply with simple example

Comment: There is no relation between primary key and stored procedure. I don't understand what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

A **stored procedure** is just a block of procedural code that is stored inside your SQL Server database.

A **primary key** is a *logical construct* on any given table to define one (or multiple) column(s) that is/are used to **uniquely and reliably** identify each row in a given table.

Stored procedure and primary key are two **totally different**, by default totally unrelated entities in a database. I don't understand why you're asking about a relationship between the two - they don't have any.